# How to balance forces in a loop-de-loop?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, friction, free-body-diagram

Imagine a car is going up a loop de loop and we look at the forces at the top of the loop.

If the car is of a sufficient speed, then it doesn’t lose contact with the surface.

This makes sense from the perspective of the car because the centrifugal force balances with gravity.

However, if we look from an observers reference frame, how do we account for the fact that both centripetal force and gravity are pointing down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the car stays on the loop, the net downward force on the car at the top of the loop provides the centripetal force needed to ensure the car is moving in a circle. In other words, in going around the curve at the top, the car necessarily has a nonzero downward component to its acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

> "How to balance forces in a loop de loop?"

Well, you only expect the forces to be balanced if the velocity is unchanging (some constant speed and direction, or zero).

In a loop de loop, the car doesn't execute a straight line uniform motion. Its velocity is constantly changing direction, and possibly magnitude.

> If the car is of a sufficient speed, then it doesn’t lose contact with the surface.
>
> [...]
>
> However, if we look from an [stationary] observers reference frame, how do we account for the fact that both centripetal force and gravity are pointing down?

Seems to me that you're expecting the car to move along the direction of the net force? However, the direction of the force and the direction of motion can be different. Remember, the direction of the force (or of a net sum of forces) *doesn't* tell you the direction the object will go. The force causes a *change* in motion, and therefore it describes the change in velocity (through being proportional to the acceleration).

More precisely, the instantaneous value of the acceleration vector tells you how the velocity of the object would change if the acceleration itself  (and thus force, for unchanging mass) was constant for 1s ($F=ma$, and the units of $a$ are meters per second, per second - a change in velocity per second). For a given time step, you multiply that acceleration with the time step (to get a linear approximation of the change in velocity). For a changing force/acceleration, you integrate over a bunch of small steps.

So, now consider, what's the velocity of a car at the top of the loop de loop? You said it yourself: "If the car is of a sufficient speed, then it doesn’t lose contact with the surface". It's because the car is already moving forward, and the surface curves to get in the way; the instantaneous downward force at the top doesn't mean the car goes straight down.

Another way to think about it, suppose it wasn't a full loop de loop - imagine it cuts off at the top, and the car just flies out. Suppose the car had sufficient speed to complete a full loop if there were one. Once the car is launched, does it drop straight down?

To build intuition further, consider what happens when you trow things. E.g., when you throw a ball at an angle, it goes up for a while, then falls down. But once it leaves your hand, the force on the ball is downwards *at all times*. The trajectory is a *curve*, and the forces aren't balanced - *otherwise*, the object would travel with uniform velocity along a straight line (or stand still).

If an object is going around in a circle, the forces aren't balanced. *Otherwise*, the object would travel with uniform velocity along a straight line (or stand still).

Comment: I'd appreciate if the downvoter(s) left a comment on what specifically is the problem?

Comment: I made the language a bit more precise, but other than that, I don't think I'm saying anything controversial here?